# How to use array to calculate Variance?

Tags: arrays, c, variance

Student new to coding here.

I have a project where I must give variance by using one dimensional arrays and using dynamic memory allocation. I am also to calculate mean, standard deviation and error as well as correlation coefficient for two lists. I have everything correct so far but have no idea how to do the rest. Here is what I have for Variance and any help is greatly appreciated as I been trying things for hours and can't figure it out.

```
for (element = first_element; element < number_of_elements; element++) {
  list1_sum = list1_sum + pow((list1_numbers[element] - list1_mean), 2);
}

variance_1 = list1_sum / (number_of_elements) - (1);
```

Comment: variance, std dev and error is for each ind. list

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you look over our [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), you may see that this is not what we call a good question; you have not specified what the problem is. I don't think that that last line does what you intend, but I can't confirm that that's the whole problem, with the limited information you've given us.

Comment: Note that the final division should be by `(number_of_elements - 1)`. The bracket placement is important there.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is [population and sample variance](https://www.scribbr.com/statistics/variance/).

OP's `variance_1 = list1_sum / (number_of_elements) - (1);` is neither.

Repaired code:

```
list1_sum = 0; // Be sure to zero the sum
end_plus1 = first_element + number_of_elements
for (element = first_element; element < end_plus1; element++) {
  list1_sum = list1_sum + pow(list1_numbers[element] - list1_mean, 2);
}

variance_population = list1_sum / (number_of_elements - 1);
variance_sample = list1_sum / number_of_elements;
```

Additional code would handle corner cases of `n <= 1` and very large values that may overflow intermediate calculations.

OP uses `first_element` rather than 0 and so perhaps `number_of_elements` needs adjustment: is that the number of elements for 0 or from `first_element`?  This answers assumes the latter.